# How are standard consumer LED dimmers built?

Tags: circuit-design, led-driver, dimmer

What would be a circuit of a shelf consumer LED dimmer that works, let’s say, with a potentiometer? Is it important/more efficient to have the dimmer circuit integrated with the 230V mains to 12V/24V power supply or this doesn’t matter much as it is a different stage?

Is it using 555 or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: `Is it using 555 or something else?` ... definitely `yes`

Answer (score 0):

‘Consumer led dimmer’ depends on exactly which one.

If we look at it the other way, then:

‘Dimmable’ led globes can be dimmed by the usual phase control dimmers you’d use for an incandescent lamp. The downside of this method is that you can’t dim the globes all the way down to 0 brightness as the power supply in the led globe needs a minimum amount of energy to function. So you get, say, 20% min brightness then off.

Contrast this to a ‘smart’ globe that has some form of wireless control. The internal power supply always has full mains and the leds are dimmed internally by pwm. This means they can be dimmed down to 0 brightness. Similarly with the Dali and 0-10V ‘bricks’ that are designed to control a string of leds as opposed to a led globe intended to replace a standard light bulb.

Would these use a 555? Possibly, but the smart and dali ones would most likely use a microcontroller. These would likely have a switched mode psu to derive the DC for the leds and maybe a constant current driver modulated by pwm.

Comment: I assumed they use PWM. I think most do(?). I understand how to build my own dimmer with 555 or an Atmel chip. Let’s ignore the smart part and talk about a dumb dimmer that uses a potentiometer. My question is rather: what would be a simple, economical circuit that would be used on mass production.

Comment: You’ve given no specifications. What is the input? What is the output? To drive what sort of led? How many? Engineers work with numbers not fluffy words.

Comment: @waverider PWM is used for constant voltage lights such as LED strips. Most bulbs and fixtures do not use constant voltage and so are unlikely to be PWM. You didn't say what type of light you're thinking of, so it could be either depending on the device type.